# Cannot assign BERT model in class field

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, bert-language-model, pytorch-lightning

I have a class that extends the LightningModule class of Pytorch Lightning and has a field bert_model. I am trying to perform the following

```py
self.bert_model = BertForTokenClassification.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')
```

However, after the execution of this line, the field bert_model is None. If I do this:

```py
bert_model = BertForTokenClassification.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')
self.bert_model = bert_model
```

the variable bert_model is initialized correctly while the class field bert_model is still None.

Any suggestions on what could be the problem?

Comment: can you provide more context, as this seems to work for me:
```from transformers import BertForTokenClassification ; model = BertForTokenClassification.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased') ; print(model)
```